# No matching function for call to... (using templates and pointers)

Tags: c++

I was doing a college work, but this isn´t working and is giving an error:
I tried many variations but they always lead to the same error.
(sorry for bad english.)

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Edge<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::Edge(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const int&)'
                     node1->edges.push_back(Edge<N,E>(end,val));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Graph class:

```
template <class N, class E>
class Graph {
    vector< Node<N,E> *> nodes;
public:
    Graph & addEdge(const N &begin, const N &end, const E &val);
    ...
```

Node class:

```
template <class N, class E>
class Node {
public:
    N info;
    vector< Edge<N,E> > edges;
    Node(N inf) {
        info = inf;
    }
};
```

Edge class:

```
template <class N, class E>
class Edge {
public:
    E value;
    Node<N,E> *destination;
    Edge(Node<N,E> *dest, E val) {
        value = val;
        destination = dest;
    }
};
```

Add Edge method: (this method is used to add a new edge to the graph, adding the edge to the correct node. Always verifies if the 2 nodes exist, and if the nodes are already connected.)

```
template<class N, class E>
Graph<N,E> & Graph<N,E>::addEdge(const N &begin, const N &end, const E &val)
{
    for(Node<N,E>* &node1 : nodes)
    {
        if (node1->info == begin)
        {
            for(Node<N,E>* &node2 : nodes)
            {
                if (node2->info == end)
                {
                    for(const Edge<N,E>& edge : node1->edges)
                    {
                        if(edge.destination == node2)
                            throw EdgeAlreadyExists<N>(begin,end);
                    }
                    node1->edges.push_back(Edge<N,E>(end,val));
                    goto FIM;
                }
            }
            throw NodeDoesNotExist<N>(end);
            goto FIM;
        }
        throw NodeDoesNotExist<N>(begin);
    }
    FIM:
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: The only `Edge` constructor takes a `Node<N, E>*` pointer and an `E` value. But `end` is of type `N`, not `Node<N, E>*`. Beyond that, it's a little unclear to me what the types `N` and `E` are supposed to represent in this code. (Node and edge weights?) It's likely that the signature for `addEdge` is incorrect because `begin` and `end` are supposed to be `Node`s but they're actually `N`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Edge` constructor takes a pointer to nodes.

```
Edge(Node<N,E> *dest, E val) {
```

but when you use it you give it something else

```
addEdge(const N &begin, const N &end, const E &val)
```

and

```
Edge<N,E>(end,val)
```

`end` should have type `Node<N,E> *` but in your code its just `const N &`.

If I have to **guess** then I would say the code should be

```
node1->edges.push_back(Edge<N,E>(node2,val));
```